# rails generate fails because of minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to follow this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-intro-to-rails-screencast-i-wish-i-had--net-22191 to understand rails.

In my gemfile, I add the group development and test with the bundles from the tutorial.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

group :development, :test do
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'turn'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'growl_notify'
end
```

After running `bundle update` - which succeeds, I run `rails g` and only get this:

```
    $ rails g
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/minitest-5.4.2/lib/minitest/unit.rb:22:in `<class:Unit>': uninitialized constant Minitest::VERSION (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/minitest-5.4.2/lib/minitest/unit.rb:21:in `<module:Minitest>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/minitest-5.4.2/lib/minitest/unit.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn/minitest.rb:9:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn/minitest.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn.rb:13:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turn-0.9.6/lib/turn.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    from /Users/christietz/Documents/projects/tasks/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:140:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I also tried to add `gem minitest` instead of `gem minitest-rails` to my Gemfile. Does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The turn gem has been mostly [abandoned](https://github.com/turn-project/turn/blob/master/README.md) since the release of Minitest 5 and was officially declared dead during the summer.  If you're looking for an alternative for improving test report formatting, try looking at [minitest-reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters).